# Problems with browser refresh and PrimeFaces 8

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm quite new at PrimeFaces as I am migrating from IceFaces.
My IceFaces application shows with a single url, page content changes and when hitting F5, current view get refreshed, without reloading the page referred by the url.
I expect this behaviour in my Primefaces app too, but this doesn't happen, as I go back to the page referred by the url, the login page in my case.

Is this an expected behaviour?

Below the  `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <display-name>oweb20-mainweb</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/extras/extras.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StickyCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.StickyCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>width</param-name>
            <param-value>250</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>height</param-name>
            <param-value>75</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StickyCaptcha</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/stickyImg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The `faces-config.xml` contains beans and navigation cases and rules, here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>SessionBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.sia.mainweb.web.SessionBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>updateManager</property-name>
            <value>#{UIUpdateManager}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>caseHome</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/Home.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

To navigate between pages, in actions, I use to return the case of the page I want to go, without redirecting to that page:

```
    public String home_action() {
        logger.info(BaseLogging.methodName() + getTraceEnteringUser());
        String caseName;
        if (userAuthenticated()) {
            boolean canContinue = checkUserFingerprint();
            if (canContinue) {
                caseName = "caseHome";
            }
        } else {
            caseName = "caseNotLoggedOn";
        }
        logger.info(BaseLogging.methodName() + getTraceExitingUser());
        return this.getNavigationManager().navigateTo(caseName);    //returns caseName
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like in IceFaces you were doing something with extensionless URL's or something like that?

Comment: If you are migrating, why not use the most recent version of PrimeFaces?

Comment: @Melloware as far as I know, but could I could be wrong, my URL figures out as `Login.xhtml`, so If there's not something that I'm missing, maybe, in my `web.xml`, the extension shows out.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I'm using this version to adeguate with another product we have in our company, but we're thinking of switching in the next future

Comment: Yep I think you are missing something in your web.xml for the Servlet Mapping OR it was something magic IceFaces was doing or if you were using the JSF Rewrite project.  Something like that